# PYTHON - FOR dentro de FOR

Tags: mysql, python

Estou realizando um select no *DB* com o *Python* e tratando este retorno.
Minha dúvida é na utilização de um `for` **dentro** de outro `for`,
utilizo o script abaixo:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                                user='root',
                                host='localhost',
                                password='***')

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("select calldate, clid, src, dst from cdr.cdr \
where calldate like '2019-02-18%'\
ORDER BY calldate desc limit 2")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for row in myresult:
    for fild in row:
        print (fild[0])
        print (fild[1])
        print (fild[2])
        print (fild[3])

mydb.close()
```

E está sendo exibido o seguinte erro:

```
# python3.6 dumpMysql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dumpMysql.py", line 18, in <module>
    print (fild[0])
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
```

Estou tentando fazer com que o `output` seja:

```
Primeira linha do select
campo0
campo1
campo2
campo3

Segunda linha do select
campo0
campo1
campo2
campo3
```

Comment: Quando você roda o código, o que fica dentro da variável "myresult"? Que tipo de objeto é alocado nela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelos comentários vc precisa "guardar" os fields em variaveis para tratamento posterior, então a sugestão é guardar esses fields em um dicionario, na verdade em uma lista de dicionarios (um dicionario para cada row):

```
lst_dicts = []
for row in myresult:
    d = {}
    d['calldate'] = row[0] 
    d['clid'] = row[1] 
    d['src'] = row[2] 
    d['dst'] = row[3] 
    lst_dicts.append(d)
```

No final vc terá uma lista de dicionários, cada um com 4 chaves/valor, representado os nomes dos campos e seus respectivos valores dentro de cada linha em `myresult`.

Answer (score 0):

Para você ter esse resultado, escreva a iteração assim:

```
for row in myresult:
    for fild in row:
        print (fild)
```

Por quê? Seu código pega cada `row` contida em `myresult` e depois em cada `row` ele pega um `fild` de cada vez. Para cada `fild` que ele pega, faz um `print(fild)` na tela.

Você não precisa colocar `fild[0]`...`fild[3]`, apenas `fild` mesmo.

Comment: Quando realizei a sua sugestão a saída foi algo perto do que preciso, mas a utilização de fild[1]...fild[3], é por que preciso tratar os campos retornados.

Comment: Você diz tratar os dados depois de exibir?

Comment: Eu preciso retornar o fild[0]  para o calldate, fild[1] para o clid, o fild[2] para src e o fild[3]para o dst

Comment: OK, vou modificar aqui pra você ter acesso aos filds depois.

Comment: Basicamente preciso jogar cada fild em uma variável para depois tratala...
A ideia é jogar tudo para dentro de um mongoDB.

Comment: Na verdade não precisa mudar a resposta. A coisa é o seguinte. Você já tem todos os filds na variável myresult. Você consegue acessá-los chamando algo do tipo myresult[0][0], por exemplo. Fazendo myresult[0][0], você pega o primeiro fild da primeira row.

Comment: Quando você coloca fild[0], fild[1], fild[2], fild[3], na verdade você está acessando uma posição dentro do objeto fild que está sendo tratado no momento. Pra conseguir o que você deseja, tem que acessar é myresult[0][0], myresult[0][1], myresult[0][2] e myresult[0][3] para os filds da primeira row, myresult[1][0], myresult[1][1], myresult[1][2] e myresult[1][3] para os filds da segunda row, e assim por diante...

Comment: Trabalhar com a variével "myresult", ja me abriu a mente, mas o que posso fazer, quando não sei o tamanho de linhas da variável "myresult"
Neste exemplo estou limitando a consulta a 2 resultados, mas na produção vou fazer o select para um dia inteiro, isto dará muitas linhas.

Comment: Você pode saber qual o tamanho do myresult usando len(myresult). Essa len() te dá o comprimento/tamanho (length em inglês) de um objeto. Com len(myresult) você vai saber quantas linhas tem seu resultado. :)